# How to remove unwanted commas from a python list

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercise from a python for beginners book. The project I'm stuck on is as follows: "Write a function that takes in a list of value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by comma and a space. Your function should be able to work with any list values passed to it"

Here is my code:

```
def passInList(spam):
       for x in range(len(spam)):
           z = spam[x] + ', ' 
           print(z,end= ' ')

spam=['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'and cats']
passInList(spam)
```

**Expected output** is - 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'.

**My output** is- 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats,'

The issue I'm having, is that I can't seems to get rid of the comma at the end of "cats".

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but: the assignment says you should return a string, but your function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce your code to use `join` where you give it the separator and what list to join together.

```
def passInList(spam):
       print(', '.join(spam))

spam=['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'and cats']
passInList(spam)
```

Comment: Thank you. (join worked)

Answer (score 2):

As people have posted here, `join` already exists. But if the exercise is meant to understand how to implement `join`, then here is one possibility:

```
def passInList(spam):
    s = spam[0]
    for word in spam[1:]:
        s += ', ' + word
    return s
```

That is you take the first word, then you concatenate each of the next words using a comma.

Another option to implement this is using functional programming, namely, in this case, the `reduce` function:

```
def passInList(spam):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + ', ' + y, spam)
```

Whenever a scheme of aggregating things, like in the previous implementation's `s += ...` is used, `reduce` comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` method:

```
spam=['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'and cats']
print(', '.join(spam))
```

Answer (score 0):

add a if statement to only add a comma if x is smaller than len(spam) -1,
or better yet, use the str class' join function

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `join` function which called with syntax `'str'.join(list)`. It joins all the elements in the list with `str` in between

```
>>> spam=['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'and cats']
>>> my_string = ', '.join(spam)
>>> my_string
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```